# AutoMapper: runtime types skip given members

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there a way to configure AutoMapper to skip certain properties while using it to map runtime types.
I create a map

```
Mapper.CreateMap(typeA, typeB)
```

Then, if I need to skip a property I add

```
.ForMember("propertyA", prop => prop.Ignore)
```

And this is fine. The question is how to achieve this for more properties and which are not know in the moment of coding.
So I need to skip all properties from some list.
Basically I think I need something like:

```
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(prop => !skipThese.Contains(prop.MemberName)))
```

Comment: You could use `ShouldMapProperty`. It's a bit global, though, so it's probably not the best approach.

Comment: Yes, it is not suitable. But thanks for getting back.

Comment: If it's not known at runtime you'll need to use Reflection to get the properties dynamically.

Comment: I am aware of this approach. Question is if it is possible to configure AutoMapper to skip properties from some list.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example?  How are you adding properties at run-time?

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it. Actually user is performing some actions and make that some things do not map any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some searching I have done it as an extension method:

```
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ExcludingThese<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression, List<String> exclude)
    {
        foreach (String stringVar in exclude)
        {
            expression.ForMember(stringVar, excl => excl.Ignore());
        }
        return expression;
    }
```